# How to debug a non-working passwordless RSA certificate in OpenSSH on Alpine?

Tags: docker, ssh, openssh, sshd, alpine-linux

I plan to write and run some integration tests using real SSH client and a SSH server. Since this requires server-level configuration, I am setting up the tests inside Docker, so a server can be built to the right spec, an OpenSSH server fired up, and the tests run.

Part of my system requires a non-root user (called `nonpriv`) to be able to `ssh` into a server on a passwordless basis. I have generated server certificates and non-root user certificates. I've set up `localhost` as a known host (so the server authenticity is already confirmed) but I am struggling to set up the cert as an authorised key. I want to be able to do `ssh localhost` as the `nonpriv` user and get a shell automatically. However it is skipping the key and going to password auth, which is not what I want.

The Docker `ENTRYPOINT` is this, so that server keys are different for every run:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# With thanks to https://github.com/danielguerra69/alpine-sshd

if [ ! -f "/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key" ]; then
    # generate fresh rsa key
    ssh-keygen -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key -N '' -t rsa
fi

if [ ! -f "/etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key" ]; then
    # generate fresh dsa key
    ssh-keygen -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key -N '' -t dsa
fi

# Prepare run dir
if [ ! -d "/var/run/sshd" ]; then
  mkdir -p /var/run/sshd
fi

# Start the SSH daemon
/usr/sbin/sshd

# Generate an SSH key for the nonpriv user
su -c /tmp/install/generate-keys.sh nonpriv

# Sleep so we can debug the server while it is running
# Will be replaced by test runner when SSH client works!
sleep 10000
```

As is usual for Docker, this is all run as `root`, so I use `su -c` towards the end to generate the user keys:

```
#!/bin/sh

mkdir -p /home/nonpriv/.ssh

# Add the server to recognised hosts
ssh-keyscan localhost >> /home/nonpriv/.ssh/known_hosts

# Generate an SSH key with an empty passphrase
ssh-keygen \
    -t rsa \
    -b 4096 \
    -f /home/nonpriv/.ssh/id_rsa \
    -N ''

# Add it to the list of authorised keys for self
ln -s /home/nonpriv/.ssh/id_rsa.pub /home/nonpriv/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

As you can see I use a symlink to add the public key to the authorised keys list. I then run the Docker container and shell in thusly (where "silly_name" is the automatically generated container name):

```
docker exec -it silly_name sh
```

From the shell I do this:

```
/ # whoami
root
/ # su nonpriv
/ $ whoami
nonpriv
/ $ ssh -vvv localhost
OpenSSH_7.4p1, LibreSSL 2.4.4
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: resolving "localhost" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to localhost [::1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/nonpriv/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/nonpriv/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/nonpriv/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/nonpriv/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/nonpriv/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/nonpriv/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/nonpriv/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/nonpriv/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to localhost:22 as 'nonpriv'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/nonpriv/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /home/nonpriv/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from localhost
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: rsa-sha2-512
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:ierfDQtTWiobxAGsyEf1PrjRcmsr5jQbZVOzcNCnBo4
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/nonpriv/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /home/nonpriv/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from localhost
debug1: Host 'localhost' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/nonpriv/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug2: key: /home/nonpriv/.ssh/id_rsa (0x5645c099ae80)
debug2: key: /home/nonpriv/.ssh/id_dsa (0)
debug2: key: /home/nonpriv/.ssh/id_ecdsa (0)
debug2: key: /home/nonpriv/.ssh/id_ed25519 (0)
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/nonpriv/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Trying private key: /home/nonpriv/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/nonpriv/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/nonpriv/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/nonpriv/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/nonpriv/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /home/nonpriv/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup keyboard-interactive
debug3: remaining preferred: password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug2: userauth_kbdint
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a keyboard-interactive packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: userauth_kbdint: disable: no info_req_seen
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: 
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
nonpriv@localhost's password:
```

From this it is clear that `/home/nonpriv/.ssh/id_rsa` is available, but it is not successful. I have tried a number of resources on the internet, often to do with permissions on the home directory, or the `~/.ssh` folder, or the `authorized_keys` file, but to no avail. I will keep trying, but it would be useful to get some information from the system as to what the issue might be.

I think it is possible to set up keys to make ssh-ing into localhost, since I have done this in my development laptop (admittedly with Mint 18 as an OS rather than Alpine/BusyBox).

Unfortunately there are no logs at all in `/var/log/`, so there is not much info to go on here. Where could I look next?

### Update

In case the sshd config could be important, I have the default one from Alpine:

```
$ less /etc/ssh/sshd_config

#   $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.100 2016/08/15 12:32:04 naddy Exp $

# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# Logging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

#PubkeyAuthentication yes

# The default is to check both .ssh/authorized_keys and .ssh/authorized_keys2
# but this is overridden so installations will only check .ssh/authorized_keys
AuthorizedKeysFile  .ssh/authorized_keys

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
#PasswordAuthentication yes
#PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to no to disable s/key passwords
#ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
#UsePAM no

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
#X11Forwarding no
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PermitTTY yes
#PrintMotd yes
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no
#UsePrivilegeSeparation sandbox
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/lib/ssh/sftp-server

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#   X11Forwarding no
#   AllowTcpForwarding no
#   PermitTTY no
#   ForceCommand cvs server
```

Comment: Do you have enabled RSAAuthentication in /etc/ssh/sshd_config? Note the `sshd` in filename

Comment: Thanks for the tip, @Robert, however that hasn't changed much. I did not have that before, but I have added it. I now get this: `/etc/ssh/sshd_config line 121: Deprecated option RSAAuthentication`. It does not seem to make a difference to the passwordless login.

Comment: @Robert, this was solved! See below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved this one, though I don't fully understand *why* this solves it. (I will accept any answers in preference to my own if anyone has an explanation).

In my `Dockerfile` I was setting up a user thus:

```
# -s specify a shell; -D = don't prompt for a password
RUN adduser -s /bin/sh -D nonpriv
```

As far as I know that is just a user with a home directory and a null password. However, it looks like I do in fact need to specify a password, so I now also do this:

```
# It looks like passwordless access does not work unless the user
# has a password!
RUN echo 'nonpriv:Password123' | chpasswd
```

That seems odd to me, since the PPK access system should not care what the password of the user is, or whether it has one.

I can now SSH into self:

```
/ $ whoami
nonpriv
/ $ ssh localhost
Welcome to Alpine!

The Alpine Wiki contains a large amount of how-to guides and general
information about administrating Alpine systems.
See <http://wiki.alpinelinux.org>.

You can setup the system with the command: setup-alpine

You may change this message by editing /etc/motd.

d4dded05c2d1:~$
```

Comment: We're implementing a multi-user SFTP server and we're enforcing the usage of RSA Keys. We've ran into the same problem, and found the same solution but I'd love it if someone had a better idea. I'd prefer to avoid creating passwords for every user in our system.

Comment: @Tony: I wasn't able to improve on this, though since it is just for tests I don't need to, and have not put a lot of effort into it. Would it be sufficient for you to create the same (complex) password for all users, and then set the shell as `/bin/false`? I think that device would stop them logging in, even if they were to obtain the password.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. So far we've set very hard passwords and configured openssh so it should only allow SFTP. I think we'll give this a try as well.

I still feel this is a an unfortunate workaround and a shortcoming in alpine.

Comment: @Tony: maybe it would be worth investigating the SSH response `receive packet: type 51`? That seems to me to be the RSA key being incorrectly rejected. I wonder if it would be worth generating a log of a successful case too, and diffing the two outputs. If you can distill it down to an obvious fault, perhaps you could add an issue on the Alpine bug list?

Answer (score 1):

In my case fully password-less ssh required also the following settings:

```
Host *
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null
```

in the `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` file in the docker

```
ENV APPUSER=myuser
    ENV UID=110
    ENV GID=110

    RUN set -x ; addgroup -g "$GID" -S "$APPUSER" && \
        adduser \
        -g "$GID" \
        -D \
        -s "/bin/bash" \
        -h "/home/$APPUSER" \
        -u "$UID" \
        -G "$APPUSER" "$APPUSER" && exit 0 ; exit 1

RUN echo "$APPUSER:secret-pass" | chpasswd
RUN ssh-keygen -A
RUN apk add --no-cache procps su-exec sudo coreutils supervisor && \
    apk add --no-cache openrc openssh && \
    mkdir -p /run/openrc/ && touch /run/openrc/softlevel && rc-update add sshd 
&& rc-status && \
rm  -rf /tmp/* /var/cache/apk/* && \
apk del .build-dependencies



USER myuser

RUN ssh-keygen -q -t rsa -N '' -C '' -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa && \
   cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys && \
   chmod 644 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Comment: I assume you don't want the password to work - does `secret-pass` not work, and if so, what part of this achieves that? I wondered if you would have to set up a null shell, but you have Bash here.

Comment: Correct. it does NOT work with null shell with this versions of sshd and alpine. I am not even sure whether or not it could work without actually providing password of the OS user - I tested it with this setup but it did not work ... The question was about password-less ssh and not password-less OS user ...

Comment: SSH users _are_ OS users, aren't they?

Comment: yes - this is the private id_rsa of the myuser OS user `-f ~/.ssh/id_rsa `. My setup did not work with OS users added without password - that is without this line `RUN echo "$APPUSER:secret-pass" | chpasswd` - the whole ssh setup did not function properly ...  , nor did it work  by setting the null shell as default for that OS user !!!